# Django media directory needs execute permission

Tags: django, file-upload, permissions, imagefield

I'm recently deploying a new Django app, and on my setup (which uses Apache), the media directory will not serve files unless the "x" permission is set on the directory (which belongs to the www-data group).

I'm not sure if this is normal behavior, since I see no immediate good reason for images to have the execute permission (seems like a big security risk). What have I done wrong?

Comment: Do you serve files through django? Are is the apache handling that?

Comment: As far as I know, it is going through Apache. No line in urls.py serves media files.

Answer (score 1):

Setting e`x`ecute on a *directory* means something very different from `x` on a *file*.

From the [excellent answer over at Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/42385)

> When applying permissions to directories on Linux, the permission bits have different meanings than on regular files.  [...]
>
> - The execute bit allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside

Setting `x` on the directory seems to be (I'm not a security expert) benign, and apparently required, so nothing to worry about.  `x` on the files is what you want to avoid.